# Elasticsearch: why is more-like-this with "ids" different from "like_text"

Tags: elasticsearch, morelikethis

I am using ES version 1.7.

I have some articles and I am trying to find similar articles based on their title. My "title" field looks like this:

`"title": {
            "type": "string",
            "store": true,
            "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
            "analyzer": "snowball"
          }`

Let's say that article id=1 has title "Persistent cramping" and  article id=2 has the title "I get cramping all the time".

If I do the following more-like-this query against article id=1, I get a match:

`{
    "query": {
        "mlt": {
            "fields": ["title"],
            "like_text": "I get cramping all the time",
            "min_term_freq": 1,
            "min_doc_freq": 1
        }
    }
}`

However, if I use the "ids" field instead, I don't get a match:

`{
    "query": {
        "mlt": {
            "fields": ["title"],
            "ids": [2],
            "min_term_freq": 1,
            "min_doc_freq": 1
        }
    }
}`

Any ideas of what could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was (quite silly, really).

The document id 2 did not exist, and thus it returned "random" matches.